# How to indent this line for pep8 compatibility

Tags: python, indentation, pep8

How can I indent the line inside the for loop so that it is compatible with pep8?

```
for ii in range(len(file_time)):
    file_time[ii] = datetime.strptime(str(file_date[ii]) + " " + str(file_time[ii]),'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f').replace(microsecond=0)
```

I've tried two of the options that the pep8 documentation offers:

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)

# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

but I still get the same error:

```
script.py:36:9:E122 continuation line missing indentation or outdented
```

Comment: What do you mean *they don't work*? The hanging indent is what I'd use here.

Comment: Are you using a tool like flake8 to check it?

Comment: what I mean is that I still get an indentation error:

Comment: Check that your indentation is consistent across the file. If You edited file with several different editors, there is a chance You have mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @paulzaba: Your question would be much improved if you actually included your actual attempt that produces the linting error you see (and not just the PEP-8 quotes). Take into account that questions here need to be useful for future visitors too; they can't see if they made the same mistake as you did without your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hanging indent should work just fine:

```
for ii in range(len(file_time)):
    file_time[ii] = datetime.strptime(
        str(file_date[ii]) + " " + str(file_time[ii]),
        '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f').replace(microsecond=0)
```

You can improve on this by avoiding using `str()` conversions (you already have strings, surely), and using `zip()` and a list comprehension:

```
file_time = [
    datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(fd, ft)
                      '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f').replace(microsecond=0)
    for fd, ft in zip(file_date, file_time)]
```

You can extract the conversion into a function too:

```
def as_dt(datestr, timestr, fmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'):
    dt = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(fd, ft), fmt)
    return dt.replace(microsecond=0)

file_time = [as_dt(fd, ft) for fd, ft in zip(file_date, file_time)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer isn't either of those - just because it's permissible, doesn't mean it's the best way. The purpose of pep8 is to improve maintainability and readability. To make it pep8 compliant, not to mention more readable, maybe you should split it apart into multiple lines.

```
TIME_FORMAT = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f"

for ii in range(len(file_time)):
    date_time = "{} {}".format(file_date[ii], file_time[ii])
    file_time[ii] = datetime.strptime(date_time, TIME_FORMAT)
    file_time[ii] = file_time[ii].replace(microsecond=0)
```

One of the reasons there is a column limit in pep8 is to encourage you to split your code apart into more readable sections. To make things as readable as possible, try to keep your code to one action per line.

Comment: thanks! I'm still doing a "test code" but as your method works too I'll use it in my final script

Answer (score 0):

The general rule in python is that expressions can contain newlines if they are surrounded by parenthesis, which is why this...

```
for ii in range(10):
    foo = 1+ 
          2+
          3
```

... generates a SyntaxError,

While this...

```
for ii in range(10):
    foo = (1+ 
          2+
          3)
```

... does not.

Also, since you mentionned an indentation error, check that you are consistently using tabs or spaces for identation.

Comment: `E122` is not a syntax error or indentation error. It is a *linting* error, where the *style guide* is violated, not syntax rules (which mixing tabs and spaces for indentation would fall under too).

Comment: Try the code yourself, the first example does generate a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" exception in both python 2.7.9 and python 3.4.2 while the other one does not.
It also happens to be a linting error /because/ it is invalid syntax.

Comment: I'm talking about the code in the question, which is *not* running into a syntax error. The OP didn't share their attempt at breaking that expression across lines, but they did share the linter error: `script.py:36:9:E122 continuation line missing indentation or outdented`.

Comment: As such, talking about syntax errors because you tried to break a logical line across multiple physical lines without parens doesn't apply here. The `strptime()` call includes parens already.

Comment: My bad, at the time of writing my answer, the question had not been edited to add the actual error message and i did not notice the edit. I see what you mean now.